# ISP causing Facebook Access denied 403

Tags: javascript, facebook, cakephp, localhost

I am using Facebook Auth on my local computer and it had been working fine until this morning. I can't figure out why I get an access denied when connecting.

`http://facebook.com/en_US/all.js`

Here is my script. I have checked it in several browsers.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '". $AppID."',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Comment: funny but i think its my ISP i switched back to my usual network and it works just fine. what can i do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Trying replacing `window.loaction.reload()` with `window.location.reload(true)`.

If this doesn't fix the problem trying another way like:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href)
```